# Changed sudoku lookup to O(1) from O(n) using prime numbers but not seeing a significant speedup in code

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, sudoku

I got the code to solve sudoku from this channel on Youtube called ComputerPhile. The algorithm was straightforward, but I felt like the check to see if a number can be in a spot, could be done faster. The code from the video linearly searches through the vertical, horizontal axes  and the corresponding 3x3 grid.

I modified the 'possible' check to use product of prime numbers with the aim of changing the possible() check from O(n) to O(1). However I did not see significant time improvement in my code.

So obviously my intuition of algorithmic complexity is wrong, but it would be great someone could point out where my intuition was off.

Input is the same for both. I did cache the prime products, but I think everything here is kosher since I am only timing the solve() function.

Here is the code from the video .

```
import numpy as np

grid = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]

def possible(y,x,n): 
    global grid

    """ linear time algorithm below """

    for i in range(0,9):
        if grid[y][i]==n: 
            return False 
    for i in range(0,9):
        if grid[i][x]==n: 
            return False
    x0 = (x//3)*3 
    y0 = (y//3)*3 
    for i in range(0,3): 
        for j in range(0,3): 
            if grid[y0+i][x0+j] ==n: 
                return False
    return True

def solve(): 
    global grid
    for y in range(9): 
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] ==0: 
                for n in range(1,10): 
                    if possible(y,x,n):
                        grid[y][x] = n 
                        solve()
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    print(np.matrix(grid))

import time 
t1 = time.time()
solve()
print(time.time() - t1)
#output of 0.00691604614258
```

modified code below leveraging prime numbers to check if its possible to add a number

```
import numpy as np 

grid = [
    [7,8,0,4,0,0,1,2,0],
    [6,0,0,0,7,5,0,0,9],
    [0,0,0,6,0,1,0,7,8],
    [0,0,7,0,4,0,2,6,0],
    [0,0,1,0,5,0,9,3,0],
    [9,0,4,0,6,0,0,0,5],
    [0,7,0,3,0,0,0,1,2],
    [1,2,0,0,0,7,4,0,0],
    [0,4,9,2,0,6,0,0,7]
]
primes = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]

p = 1
for i in primes: 
    p = p*i

total = p  #3234846615


prime_map = dict(zip(primes,range(1,10)))
int_map = dict(zip(range(1,10), primes))

grid_map = {} 
for i in range (9): 
    for j in range(9): 
        grid_map[(j//3, i//3)] = total

vertical_map = dict(zip(range(0,9),[total]*9))

horizontal_map = dict(zip(range(0,9),[total]*9))


def new_possible(y,x,n):
    global grid_map 
    global grid 
    global vertical_map 
    global horizontal_map 

    """attempted O(1) algorithm here"""

    if vertical_map[x]%n!=0: 
        return False 
    if horizontal_map[y]%n!=0: 
        return False 
    x0 = (x//3)
    y0 = (y//3)
    if grid_map[(y0,x0)]%n!=0: 
        return False
    return True 

def initial_update(): 
    global grid_map 
    global grid 
    global vertical_map 
    global horizontal_map
    global int_map
    for y in range(9): 
        for x in range(9): 
            num = grid[y][x] 
            if num!=0:
                vertical_map[x] = vertical_map[x] // int_map[num]
                horizontal_map[y] = horizontal_map[y] //int_map[num]
                grid_map[(y//3, x//3)] = grid_map[(y//3, x//3)] // int_map[num]
initial_update()

def new_solve(): 
    global grid_map 
    global grid 
    global vertical_map 
    global horizontal_map
    global int_map

    for y in range(9): 
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] ==0: 
                for n in range(1,10): 
                    if new_possible(y,x,int_map[n]):
                        grid[y][x] = n  
                        vertical_map[x] = vertical_map[x]//int_map[n]
                        horizontal_map[y] = horizontal_map[y]//int_map[n]
                        grid_map[((y//3),(x//3))] = grid_map[((y//3),(x//3))]  //  int_map[n]
                        new_solve()
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                        vertical_map[x] = vertical_map[x]*int_map[n]
                        horizontal_map[y] = horizontal_map[y]*int_map[n]
                        grid_map[((y//3),(x//3))] = grid_map[((y//3),(x//3))] * int_map[n]
                return
    print(np.matrix(grid))

import time
t1 = time.time()
new_solve()
print(time.time() - t1)
# output of 0.00550096549988
```

Comment: Could you explain which part is O(n) and O(1)

Comment: yeah let me comment it in the code, basically if you see the first section, you are doing a linear search across vertical, horizontal and 3x3 grid.

Comment: Have you measured how much of the running time is spent on `possible`? If it's only a small portion of the overall running time, then it could be why overall there are not much improvement. Also, a linear search on 9 cells will not be too significantly different from doing a single computation. You can also read more on [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Comment: Would it not be cheaper to hold each cell as 2^n, where n is the number in the cell, and then OR cells together for column, row and 3x3 box ?  You can then OR and NOT to find what's allowed in a cell ?  Trying a cell and back-tracking looks pretty straightforward, too.  FWIW, division is likely to be a slow operation :-(  Is it worth keeping each cell on one of nine lists, by number of possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time seems to be spent in the loops and recursion. Using numpy and some other optimization, I could not achieve better than a 50% time reduction without changing the main looping/recursion approach.  I would suggest you focus on finding a way to cut down on the recursion depth because speeding up the validity check will only get you relatively small improvements.

for example, this version uses a mask for each position that identifies all other positions that are "related" to it (i.e. same line, same column, same block). This provides a very fast way of knowing if a number is in conflict with any given position.

```
b      = np.arange(81).reshape((9,9))
rows   = b//9
cols   = b%9 
blocks = (b//9//3)+3*(b%9//3)
mask   = (rows[:,:,None,None]==rows)*1 \
       + (cols[:,:,None,None]==cols)*1 \
       + (blocks[:,:,None,None]==blocks)*1
mask   = mask > 0

def solve2(grid):
    for y in range(9): 
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] ==0: 
                for n in range(1,10): 
                    if np.any(grid[mask[y,x]]==n): continue
                    grid[y][x] = n
                    if solve2(grid): return True
                    grid[y][x] = 0
                return False
    print(grid)
    return True
```

I also added a boolean return value to stop the search when a solution is found.